# can you use Form Wizard for Model Forms in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have one model and I've created a form out of the model using `ModelForm`.  Now, I want to spread the form across two pages.  For example, the first three fields will appear on the first page then the user clicks next and the last three fields appear on the second page. Then he clicks submit and the user submitted data is added to the database.

I took a look at the docs for the Form Wizard and it seems like it would work for model forms as well?  Can someone confirm this?

And if it does, can someone explain the process of creating a `WizardView` class.

This example is given in the docs and I don't understand what the second two parameters are.  Is form_list just a list of form objects that you've instantiated based on your form classes?  And what is `**kwargs`?

```
class ContactWizard(SessionWizardView):
    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        do_something_with_the_form_data(form_list)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/page-to-redirect-to-when-done/')
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Form Wizard is being built into Django 1.4 so is a good way to go about this. It should do what you want, but you may need a couple of tweaks.

Don't worry about the `kwargs` in `done()` at the moment - you're not going to need them.

`form_list` is the list of forms that you want to use for your steps - from `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^contact/$', ContactWizard.as_view([ContactForm1, ContactForm2])),
)
```

`[ContactForm1, ContactForm2]` will be passed to `done()` as `form_list`.

What you will need to do is break your `ModelForm` into separate forms. The easiest way to do this (if you want your model on several forms) is to not use `ModelForm` but just create your own form. It's pretty easy:

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm1(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    sender = forms.EmailField()

class ContactForm2(forms.Form):
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

Once your forms reflect the portions of your model, just create the `views` and `patterns` as described in the [docs](http://readthedocs.org/docs/django-formwizard/en/feature-backport/gettingstarted.html#conditionally-view-skip-specific-steps) and set `do_something_with_the_form_data(form_list)` to a function that completes your model from the form data and then does a save.

You could use `ModelForm` but - only if you can persuade it to produce different forms for Form Wizard to use for each step - that's going to be the tricky part.

Comment: If you choose to use `ModelForm`, you can use `fields` or `excludes` to control the fields visible for each step.

Answer (score 25):

Say your model has two fields

```
class AModel( Model ):
    fieldA = CharField()
    fieldB = CharField()
```

We want to set each field in a separate step using a `FormWizard`. So we create two `ModelForm`s, each showing one field:

```
class Form1( ModelForm ):
    class Meta:
        model = AModel
        fields = ( 'fieldA', )

class Form2( ModelForm ):
    class Meta:
        model = AModel
        fields = ( 'fieldB', )
```

We call our form wizard `AWizard`; the `url.py` entry should look something like

```
url( r'^$', AWizard.as_view( [ Form1, Form2 ] ) ),
```

In the implementation of `AWizard` we need to make sure all the forms write their data to a single instance, which we then save to the database:

```
class AWizard( SessionWizardView ):
    instance = None

    def get_form_instance( self, step ):
        if self.instance is None:
            self.instance = AModel()
        return self.instance

    def done( self, form_list, **kwargs ):
        self.instance.save()
```

Notice that we override the method `get_form_instance`. This method returns the model instance the forms bind to.

You might think (I did), that this method creates an instance for the first request (the first step of the wizard), and then keeps using that same instance for all steps.

Actually, it's a little more complicated. For each request a new instance of `AWizard` is created, which in turn creates a new `AModel` instance. So, the steps don't share a single instance to start with.

The magic happens when the last form is submitted. At this point all forms are revalidated, each form calls `get_form_instance` and they end up populating a single `AModel` instance.

That instance is then saved in `done`.

Comment: These infos about the get_form_instance() were really helpful !! Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

The view proposed by @wuerg did not work for me, I had to do this:

```
class AWizard( SessionWizardView ):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.instance = AModel()
        return super(ApplyWizard, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_form_instance( self, step ):
        return self.instance

    def done( self, form_list, **kwargs ):
        self.instance.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(thanks))
```

Comment: i want to display my form on radio button selecton of 1st form..how can i do this?can u guide me?

Answer (score -1):

I had to alter the solution of @wuerg and @madmen to work in my usecase (saving the Model after every step). The big advantage of this approach is that it always uses the same instance of the `AModel` instead of  creating a new instance for every step:

```
class AWizard(SessionWizardView):
    instance = AModel()

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(AWizard, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_form_instance(self, step):
        return self.instance

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        self.save_model()
        return render_to_response('done.html')
```

Comment: From my tests, this solution does not work. If you open another window to simulate another user and try to navigate through the wizard, you will use the same instance and, as a consequence, have your fields pre-filled with the first user's data !